# Facing an issue in Database creation in Flask Documentation Tutorial Nonetype object has no attribute executescript

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Tutorial link : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/

I am trying out the official Flask tutorial on a Windows 10 Python 3.9.0 environment in VS Code, DB is sqlite.

Have defined the directory structure - Flask_Tutorial\Flaskr. Below are my **init**.py and db.py files.

****init**.py**

```
import os

from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY = 'DEV',
        DATABASE = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'Flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py',silent=True)
    else:
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass
    
    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello World !'
    
    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)
     
    return app
```

**db.py**

```
import sqlite3
import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))


@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')        

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

**sqlite.schema**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;

CREATE TABLE user (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE post (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES user (id)
);
```

Next I set the variables :

```
> set FLASK_APP=flaskr
> set FLASK_ENV=development
```

Now when I run `flask init-db` from the Flaskr folder, I get the following error :

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'executescript'**

The Flaskr.sqlite is generated, but I see not Tables in the database.

I can see there is an issue in Creating Tables and hence the None is returned leading to the error.

Can someone help ?

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXF49.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I had missed the return statement for the database. After adding that, it works smoothly.

Corrected db.py below :

````
import sqlite3
import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))


@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')        

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command) ```

Had missed the '''return g.db''' statement.
````